# How to wrap the 90 degrees rotated text in a table cell

Tags: tables, line-breaking, rotating

in Microsoft word I have a table which has the following structure.

[image]

Now, I need to make a similar table in LaTex to submit a publication, I tried with the following code,

```
%%***************************************************************
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{article}%                         *
\usepackage{graphicx}%                                           *

\begin{document}
%===============Table Starts====================================
Table 1. This is a table 
\begin{center}%[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{l rrrrrrrr}\hline
\rotatebox{90}{Number of 
Married Years}  & \rotatebox{90}{Observed Frequency (Year 1)}   & \rotatebox{90}{Expected Poisson Frequency (Year 1)} & 
\rotatebox{90}{Expected Binomal Frequency (Year 1)} & \rotatebox{90}{Expected Normal Frequency (Year 1)}    & \rotatebox{90}{Observed Frequency (Year 2)} & \rotatebox{90}{Expected Poisson Frequency (Year 2)} & \rotatebox{90}{   Expected Binomial
Frequency (Year 2) } & \rotatebox{90}{Expected Normal Frequency (Year 2)}\\\hline
            0     & x     & y     & z     & a     & b     & c     & d     & e \\
            1     & x     & y     & z     & a     & b     & c     & d     & e \\
            2     & x     & y     & z     & a     & b     & c     & d     & e \\
            3     & x     & y     & z     & a     & b     & c     & d     & e \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab1}
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

This code produces a table like the below,

[image]

It would be  a great help if you could guide me in wrapping the rotated text in the first row of the table.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 14):

`\parbox` is an obvious choice here. I've wrapped this in a command `\spheading[<width>]{<stuff>}` (default of width is `10em`), to avoid duplication of angles:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newcommand{\spheading}[2][10em]{% \spheading[<width>]{<stuff>}
  \rotatebox{90}{\parbox{#1}{\raggedright #2}}}
\begin{document}
%===============Table Starts====================================
Table 1. This is a table 
\begin{center}%[htbp]
  \begin{tabular}{l *{8}{r}}
    \hline
    \spheading{Number of Married Years} & 
    \spheading{Observed Frequency (Year 1)} & 
    \spheading{Expected Poisson Frequency (Year 1)} & 
    \spheading{Expected Binomal Frequency (Year 1)} & 
    \spheading{Expected Normal Frequency (Year 1)} & 
    \spheading{Observed Frequency (Year 2)} & 
    \spheading{Expected Poisson Frequency (Year 2)} & 
    \spheading{Expected Binomial Frequency (Year 2)} & 
    \spheading{Expected Normal Frequency (Year 2)} \\
    \hline
    0     & x     & y     & z     & a     & b     & c     & d     & e \\
    1     & x     & y     & z     & a     & b     & c     & d     & e \\
    2     & x     & y     & z     & a     & b     & c     & d     & e \\
    3     & x     & y     & z     & a     & b     & c     & d     & e \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

Without more information, I've kept the column alignment as-is. However, a centred display would look better here.

Comment: Very simple answer @Werner....  how can we have it in the center? :)

Comment: @karathan - To center-set the columns, you could replace `*{8}{r}` with `*{8}{c}` in the argument of the `tabular` environment.

Comment: Really with LaTeX sometimes laugh at myself ... the solution is in my legs and I look at the stars.:) I tried to do it with, `\centering` and the result was something else, thanks @Mico

Comment: The ascenders of the b and d nearly touch the rule, so I think you might want a little more space between the rule and the entries.

Comment: Thank you very much for the timely answer Werner. Yes, a center display looks better.

Comment: thanks for the nice answer. If I wanna override the `newcommand{\spheading}[2][10em]{% \spheading[<width>]{<stuff>}
  \rotatebox{90}{\parbox{#1}{\raggedright #2}}}` inline in the table cell, how am I gonna do that? i.e. change the width

Comment: @Amir: You would use `\spheading[15em]{<stuff>}` (or some other length) instead of just `\spheading{<stuff>}`, which defaults to a `\parbox` of width `10em`.